# migration tt_news to tx_news

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tt-news, tx-news

I've an TYPO3 4.5 Installation with a lot of tt_news elements. Also used are DAM and event extensions. For an overview I add an image.

We are working now on a TYPO3 7.6 page and of cource want to have the complete old news on this site. For standard news I know the importer of tx_news. The problem here is the extensive use of additional extensions. I would like to know if there is a more complete solution for migration or something like a how to. Or might it be a better solution to use the new tt_news extension? What about migration then?

This seems a huge task, I've not expected. Hope for some support. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to identify which functionality you want to keep and which is not covered by existing solutions like using shariff for social sharing. 
After that you can actually migrate the records as you know now how the fields are named you need to fill. There are several hooks and signals you can use in news extension and all of those are described in the manual of news, see https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Documentation/DeveloperManual/ExtendNews/ImportService/Index.rst

Comment: I'd like to point out that at first it is really important to upgrade to a running TYPO3 6.2. On this way I recommend to throw all extensions away which are not needed for the main job of getting tt_news and related things working in tx_news. I also used the extension dam_falmigration before the news_ttnewsimport. 
For mbl_newsevent there is a importer allready implementet in news_ttnewsimport to migrate to roq_newsevent. Whats great. This one can be used as a example how to use import also other data from third-party extensions.